# Where to find Unturned Workshop

Tags: steam, unturned, steam-workshop

I poked around the internet and can't seem to find how to get to the Unturned Workshop on steam. I bought Gold and have Beta installed already. I want to get the Canada Map back in for 3.0 but the PEI has a lock on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> With this update the majority of core Workshop features are
>   implemented! If you head on over you'll soon find tons of new content
>   to play with. To view it you will need to join the Unturned Workshop
>   beta group here: http://steamcommunity.com/groups/304930_Workshop

[Source](http://steamcommunity.com/games/304930/announcements/detail/217635038937360434)

Comment: Thanks! this helped me out a lot. I joined and realized that I needed to refresh the contents section for something to show up.